# Custom linux kernel syscall wrapper function

Tags: c, linux, kernel, system-calls

i am writing a custom system call for linux kernel
everything works fine with the function call and now i am trying
to create a wrapper function in order to use the function normally in any program
without using the syscall (call)

what i have done so far is

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<linux/unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

long *__wrap_process_info(int myid , void *udata)
{
    return syscall(337 , myid , udata);
}
```

my system call returns -1 on error and 0 if executed correctly
my question is , how to make the wrapper function return the syscall return value ?
and ,do i need to include a main in the wrapper function ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the `*` as a wildcard and not pointer notation. Your implementation is already returning the value returned by the function `syscall`. In case there is an error, it's code is stored in `errno` variable, which you might want to copy to some additional parameter you will pass to your function:

```
long <???>__wrap_process_info(int myid , void *udata, long *err )
{
    long result;
    result = syscall(337 , myid , udata);
    *err = errno;
    return result;
}
```